# Form data to be fetched and stored in a json string variable using angular and NO-SQL

Tags: angularjs, json, forms

Here is my registration form and I want all the form fields to be stored in a json string variable using angular and then post that json string to a certain url. When the user is registered it must show "successfully registered" message but if email_id or username already exist server should send back form data in with error. Below is registration form.

```
    <form name="myForm" class="register--form" ng-submit="register()" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
       <input class="register--first-input" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="user.firstname" ng-required="true">
       <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="myForm.firstname.$invalid && myForm.firstname.$touched">You must enter your first name.</p>

       <input class="register--last-input" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="user.lastname" ng-required="true">
       <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="myForm.lastname.$invalid && myForm.lastname.$touched">You must enter your last name.</p>

       <input class="register--email-input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" ng-required="true">
       <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="myForm.email.$invalid && myForm.email.$touched">Must be a valid email.</p>

       <input class="register--password-input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" ng-required="true">
       <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="myForm.password.$invalid && myForm.password.$touched">You must enter a password.</p>
   </fieldset>
     <button type="submit" class="register--submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Register</button>
     <span>or</span>
    <a class="login--register" ng-href="#/login">Login</a>
  </form>
```

Below is login form

```
   <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.login()" role="form">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.username" required />
        <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.password" required />
        <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

        <a href="#/register" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller where you have the button clicked method create a variable like and it will have the values in the key named same as the ng modle

```
$scope.show={};
```